# SQLLite ordering by date error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to order the list by date like this but I am getting a error:

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE +
   "WHERE calendar < '2016-1-00' + ORDER BY calendar ASC";
```

(1) near "<": syntax error

What am I doing wrong

Comment: The + before ORDER BY does not appear to make sense.

Comment: You need a space before the WHERE

Comment: You're missing a white space before `WHERE` in the query. Also, what data type is the `calendar` column -- `DATE` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan thanks fixed that. unicorn2 thanks done. Mick Mnemonic it is a text and its fixed answer is posted!

Comment: Okay, just a heads up that you're usually better off storing dates as `DATE`s. If you insist to store them as strings, each component should be fixed length (zero-padded) so that comparisons work as expected (e.g. `2016-9` vs `2016-09` vs `2016-10`).

Answer (score 1):

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS +
   " WHERE calendar < '2016-1-00' ORDER BY calendar ASC";
```

This is the working answer. Thank you to those who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You have two typo errors:

1) Add and extra space after the TABLE concatenation

2) Remove the "+" symbol that is located after the date

Your code should look like the following one:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE calendar < '2016-1-00' ORDER BY calendar ASC";
```

One important thing:
SQLite doesn't have "date" or "datetime" types, so you have to save  the dates as integer (int) using a unix timestamp or the inverse notation date without symbols (yyyymmdd).

I recommend you to use the inverse notation date since it only requires 8 bytes and SQLite order and search operations are going to be performed faster. Remember that inverse notation should use left padding zeroes when value is less than 10, so 20160301 (01 March 2016) should not be represented as 201631.